# Sulu: how to properly rename / remove a webspace

Tags: sulu

it looks that the case to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58237053/sulu-massive-search-bundle-exception) has it's origin in a renamed webspace. We had one for a while, where we changed the key at some point.

What is the correct way in sulu to savely delete or rename a webspace?

Thx a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by [@Alex in this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58293801/2776727), the solution is something like:

```
bin/adminconsole doctrine:phpcr:node:remove /cmf/oldwebspacekey
bin/websiteconsole doctrine:phpcr:node:remove /cmf/oldwebspacekey
```

A backup before running this commands is recommended, but it seems to work rather stable.